# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

May I know why that error keeps pointing to "String isEmailVerified ...."?

```
public JsonResult GetMemberCounts([FromBody] ChartFilterRequest filter)
        {
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(filter.MainFilter.First(m => m.Name == "startDate").Value as string);
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(filter.MainFilter.First(m => m.Name == "endDate").Value as string);
            String isEmailVerified = filter.MainFilter.First(m => m.Name == "isEmailVerified").Value as string;


            var data = _dashboardComponent.GetMemberCount(startDate, endDate, isEmailVerified);

            return new JsonResult(data);
        }
```

Comment: One of your `filter.MainFilter.First(...)`  is failing because no according element can be found ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` instead of `First` and `Last`, these methods will return the default value of the type they are invoked for if no elements match the lambda expression you provide as a parameter.

In your project, You just use  `filter.MainFilter.First(xxxx)` to select the data, So if no elements match the lambda expression you provide as a parameter,`First()` will throw an exception, So here will report this error.